# I have Destiny, including the Taken King, downloaded on PS3. What is the least I must buy to play it on PS4?

Tags: destiny

I bought the Ghost Edition in 2014, which included the expansion pack.
I do hope Bungie don't expect us to buy the whole game all over again

Answer (score 1):

If you bought Destiny on release, you may be able to upgrade. [Check this article for details](http://www.cinemablend.com/m/games/Destiny-PS4-Xbox-One-Free-With-PS3-Or-Xbox-360-Copy-67153.html).

Anyone who bought Destiny digitally before Jan 15th of 2015 could upgrade for free, but if you purchased after that, you're SOL. Then there was a brief trade in window in September, but that was at GameStop.

Comment: I brought Destiny on 360 and it transferred to One.

Comment: @Brok3n updated with the old Activision upgrade deal

Comment: On release of the game.

Comment: it would be ideal if we could have confirmation if the upgrade was available before the date, or only to accounts created before the date. There is no way for the developers to know when you first purchased the game, unless they intend to look at you receipt. The later is incredibly unlikely, if not, impossible.

Comment: Upgrade offer only applied to a digital purchase.  If other stores offered a trade in deal that was separate from the publishers deal